# SQL Server Profiler bottom pane

Tags: sql, sql-server, profiler, trace

I'm currently using SQL Server 2012, but I've noticed this behavior back several versions.

Say you run a SQL Server Profiler session.  You then select a bunch of lines in the profiler, they get displayed in the bottom pane, I'm not sure what it's called, but it has the T-sql that's actually run by profiler in there.

However, if you look closely it truncates the queries.  From copying and pasting, it appears that it can only hold 16k of data.  Does anyone know of a way to increase this size, or any documentation of exactly what the limit is?

-Eric

Comment: You should try a server-side trace (saving to a file or table) instead of the clunky UI (which is also a performance killer).

Comment: That's always been a problem in the bottom pane, trying to get it to display all the results from columns with big widths is not too clever either.

Comment: So Microsoft never bother to update the bottom pane? Of course, I am not looking for unlimited copying, but at least it should allow copying more data.

Comment: I just answered the question with what works most of the time for me now: File > Export > Extract Sql Server Events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd forgotten all about this thread.  What I do now with SQL Server Profiler 18 is do a File > Export > Extract Sql Server Events.  I then open the saved SQL Script in SSMS.  I have also tried server side tracing, but I do still occasionally run into problems with huge LINQ queries where they still get truncated.  See [SQL Server Profiler text data gets truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75187144/sql-server-profiler-text-data-gets-truncated)