# SQL Server Profiler text data gets truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I'm running SQL Server Profiler and I'm seeing some large LINQ queries are getting truncated in the TextData.

It looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Project91].[C14] AS [C1], 
    [Project91].[C1] AS [C2], 

etc...

[Project33].[MyField] AS [MyField], 
[Project33].[MyField2] AS [MyField2], 
',N'@p__linq__30 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__29 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__31 

etc...
```

There's no way that query would end with a comma like this before the parameters list.

Is there a way to increase the size of the field?

The version of SQL Server Profiler that I'm running is:

```
SQL Server Profiler                     15.0.18424.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)     16.100.47021.0+7eef34a564af48c5b0cf0d617a65fd77f06c3eb1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 10.0.19041.2486
Microsoft MSXML                         3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework                4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        10.0.19045
```

Comment: how are you capturing the profiler trace? Are you saving it to a table using varchar(max) columns?

Comment: Could it be that you're viewing the trace in management studio? It can cut off the text in the column. Trace itself should not get cut off unless we're talking gigs of SQL. Although, since you mention LINQ, it's possible :D

Comment: I've tried viewing the trace in SQL Profiler and I've tried saving it to a table using a ntext length of 16 column

Comment: It's a big query, but it doesn't seem ridiculously large.  Notpad++ says that the portion I'm able to view has 3731 lines.  I saved it to a text file and it's 982 kb.